# take corresponding values from first list and add to another list in python

Tags: python

I have two list of tuples as following:

```
actions = [(2, 1), (1, 0), 'lift 4', (2, 1), 'down 2', (1, 2), 'lift 4', 'down 2']
costs = [(2, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Here is the end result I want:

```
final_list = [(2, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3),'lift 4', (2, 1, 3),'down 2', (1, 2, 3),'lift 4','down 2' ]
```

What am I doing here.. The first two elements of tuple corresponds to (x,y) coordinates.. and then strings are "actions" i take in that coordinate.
Now, in the "costs" list.. based on the motion (diagonal motion  has cost 3 whereas linear motion has cost 2), I am appending cost to the tuple, ignoring the actions.

How do I merge these two lists so that i get the resulting "final_list"

Comment: `final_list` is being assigned an invalid Python literal.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: sorry had a typo.. fixed

Comment: Your best bet is to use some intermediate data structure to group the tuples in both lists by `(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather straighforward approach:

```
costs.reverse()
final_list = []
for action in actions:
    if isinstance(action, tuple):
        # assume that costs in the order as actions
        final_list.append(costs.pop())
    else:
        final_list.append(action)
final_list
```

Comment: Nice hack. Could also use `pop(0)` and skip the `reverse` step.

Comment: @TomZych, yes, but `pop(0)` has *O(n)* time complexity while `pop()` is just *O(1)*, so overall complexity of an algorithm in my case is just *O(n)* instead of *O(n^2)* in case of `pop(0)`. I'm not sure, does performance matter in this case (does OP have arrays long enough), but prefer to use faster algorithms by default if it is easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to simply treat `costs` as a lookup table. First,
convert it to a handy `dict`:

```
cost_dict = {i[:2] : i for i in costs}

{(1, 2): (1, 2, 3), (1, 0): (1, 0, 3), (2, 1): (2, 1, 3)}
```

Then conditionally convert the values in `actions`:

```
final_list = [cost_dict[i] if isinstance(i, tuple) else i for i in actions]

[(2, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), 'lift 4', (2, 1, 3), 'down 2', (1, 2, 3), 'lift 4', 'down 2']
```

Comment: Use of `isinstance()` is not required if you instead use `cost_dict.get(i, i)` when generating the final list.

Comment: @mhawke Good idea.

Comment: Hmm.. there is a bug in this implementation.. if two same actions have different costs, then in the map.. the last action cost will be noted..

Comment: @Fraz Well, yes. It does sound like `costs` represents a function, though.

Answer (score 1):

First create a dictionary to map the actions to costs:

```
actions = [(2, 1), (1, 0), 'lift 4', (2, 1), 'down 2', (1, 2), 'lift 4', 'down 2']
costs = [(2, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
cost_map = {cost[:2] : cost for cost in costs}
```

Now you can use `dict.get()` with a default value to process the actions list:

```
final_list = [cost_map.get(action, action) for action in actions]
>>> final_list
[(2, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), 'lift 4', (2, 1, 3), 'down 2', (1, 2, 3), 'lift 4', 'down 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the position of tuples `actions` and `costs` lists are mapped and are in order, in order to achieve the desired result you may create an intermediate list to store the index of `tuple` object in `actions` list as:

```
>>> actions = [(2, 1), (1, 0), 'lift 4', (2, 1), 'down 2', (1, 2), 'lift 4', 'down 2']
>>> costs = [(2, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> tuple_position = [i for i, a in enumerate(actions) if isinstance(a, tuple)]
>>> tuple_position
[0, 1, 3, 5]
```

Then update the values from `costs` list to the `actions` list based on the previous indexes as:

```
>>> final_list = list(actions)  # copy of `actions` list as you want the desired
                                # result in the form of new list
>>> for i, cost in zip(tuple_position, costs):
...     final_list[i] = cost
...
>>> final_list
[(2, 1, 3), (1, 0, 3), 'lift 4', (2, 1, 3), 'down 2', (1, 2, 3), 'lift 4', 'down 2']
```